# C# FileInfo returns null despite the file exists and contains data

Tags: c#, windows, forms, file

I created a setup project in visual studio 2013 for a windows forms application. my Setup project contains an SQL script file .sql . When the app runs for first time it should run this script and create the database for my app.

i Added the script file inside the Application folder of the setup proj

[image]

[image]

When i install my application and tries to read the script it returns empty  string !!!

i am gonna get crazy... please somebody tell me what is wrong .. ??

as you can se below

[image]

the install.sql file is inside my program files folder as it should (439 KB)

but when i debug i get this...

[image]

as you can see it says the length is ZERO !!!!

what am i missing ????

Comment: Is the file in AlaCarteDesktop.Setup\install.sql the one you are showing with 439 kb?

Comment: Yes this is ! the file exists and is there when i install my app ! but when my app tries to read it it says that it EXISTS but it is empty

Comment: Did you search for the file name to see if there are other copies around?

Comment: how do you set InstallSqlPath ?

Comment: i install Sql path like this

   WorkingDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
   

InstallSqlPath = Path.Combine(WorkingDir, "install.sql");

Comment: @tofutim is saying you have at least two different `install.sql`s. Click on the one inside Visual Studio, select Properties; what is its Build Action? What is its Copy to Output Directory value.

Comment: there is only one install sql... my file property is set to copyalways as Copy to output directory... but my problem is not when i run it in debug mode or release (it works) my problem is when i package my project in the setup project.. of course i add the install sql file inside the setup project in the root of application folder

Comment: You don't have permissions?

Comment: i dod not get any exception  try reading it

Comment: Is it possible that the file is open by some application to write ? also, length is not exactly a real time function call. you might want to try refreshing before querying for length https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could be file permission thing, change the file to be accessible by everyone

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It was saying that the file is in use for a some strange reason.. did not manage to solve this strange issue.... i renamed the file to .txt so now it runs in every machine without problems.